# Maximal subgroup in $S_{10}$

Tags: gr.group-theory, symmetric-groups

Consider the set of unordered pairs  $\{(i,j)\}$, $i<j, i=1,2, \ldots, 2k+1$, $j=i+1, \dots, 2k+2$, and the group $G=S_{k(2k+1)}$ of all permutations of those pairs.
Is the subgroup of the permutations of type $g[(i,j)]=(gi,gj)$, $g\in S_{2k+1}$ -- a  maximal subgroup of $G$?

Answer (score 10):

$S_5$ is not a maximal subgroup of $S_{10}$ in this way, as it is contained in a subgroup $\mathop{\rm Aut}(S_6)$.

General references for this question are Halberstadt, "On certain maximal subgroups of symmetric or alternating groups" and Newton and Benesh, "A classification of certain maximal subgroups of symmetric groups" which between them give a complete answer as to when the action of $S_n$ on $m$ element subsets gives rise to a maximal subgroup of the symmetric group of degree $\binom{n}{m}$.

Comment: Another convenient reference is: Liebeck, Praeger, Saxl, A classification of the maximal subgroups of the finite alternating and symmetric groups, Journal of Algebra Volume 111, Issue 2, December 1987, Pages 365-383